# Положение div внизу объекта

Tags: html, css

столкнулся с выравниваем div внизу другого обьекта,Но не могу понять как это можно реализовать,

хочу чтобы было вот так

[image: хочу чтобы было так]

но у меня вот так ((((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` ------ на родителя `position: relative;`

Comment: оу, благодарен)))))Не знал что так легко решить))))Все заработало)Спасибо)

Comment: не за что, желаю успехов